# App module not available, despite declaring it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've used Angular in a project once before, but trying to get a quick little something set up again is giving me this:

```
Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
```

As far as I can tell I've declared `app` properly in my `app.js`.

I made a little plunker for convenience: http://plnkr.co/edit/FWHQ5ZDAByOWsL9YeMUH?p=preview

Comment: [Fixed](http://plnkr.co/edit/XXAV4eLW4c3JTQSIkvf2?p=preview). Added Application controller and removed dependencies from dashboard controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss the `.` on the source file:

Replace

```
`<script src='/app.js'></script>`
```

with

```
`<script src='./app.js'></script>`
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realised that I was using `node` to serve content last time, with static paths configured (copy-pasted from old project).